# Changing the abstract title to 抽象

Tags: abstract, chinese

I want to change the title of my first abstract to "抽象"

I have tried

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
    \begin{abstract}
    \addto{\captionschinese}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{抽象}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{抽象}

     你好, blabla

     关键词： 

     中图分类号：F276.6

     \pagestyle{plain}
     \pagenumbering{arabic}
     \end{CJK*}
     \end{abstract}
     \newpage
```

This puts 抽象 in the TOC, but the title of the abstract remains the same, "Abstract"
Moreover, I want to add page numbers to the abstracts but they do not appear when I use this code.

Comment: Please post a complete MWE.

Comment: In your place, i would use specific chinese classes (ctex) with LuaLaTeX. If correctly used, it should give the expected result by default.

Comment: the `addto`  directive should definitely go above the `abstract` environment.

Comment: I only need Chinese for a few parts. The main text is in English, and I have a second abstract in English.

Comment: Without a minimal working example, ... who knows? I still think, the `\addto` macro should be outside the `abstract` environment. Just by looking, don't know what it might bring. We don't even know which documentclass you are using.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

Comment: Not related to the technical question you asked, the chinese word "抽象" means "existing in thought or as an idea but not having a physical or concrete existence.", which is one of the meanings of "Abstract", but it doesn't have the meaning of "a summary of the contents of a book, article, or formal speech", the word you want is "摘要".

Comment: This is still completely useless to me as it does not compile. Also,  is the chinese language  important,  or could this be reproduced with simple english?

Comment: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/ <- what we need.

Answer (score 2):

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexrep}
% \usepackage[english]{babel}       
% \usepackage{CJKutf8}
% \usepackage{titlesec}
% \pagestyle{plain}
% \pagenumbering{arabic}
\ctexset{
    abstractname={抽象},
    }

\begin{document}
% \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
% \renewcommand{\abstractname}{抽象}
\begin{abstract}
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{抽象}

你好, 
blabla

关键词：金融控股公司  发展模式 
中图分类号：F276.6

% \pagestyle{plain}
% \pagenumbering{arabic}
\end{abstract}
% \end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

I think what you need is "摘要" instead of "抽象", if so, comment `\ctexset{}`.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that this works:

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}       
   \usepackage{CJKutf8}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \pagestyle{plain}
   \pagenumbering{arabic}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}
  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{抽象}
  \begin{abstract}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{抽象}

  你好, 
   blabla

  关键词：金融控股公司  发展模式 
  中图分类号：F276.6

  \pagestyle{plain}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \end{abstract}
  \end{CJK*}
```

Comment: Doing the redefinition before the abstract environment. Sounds familiar

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume you are able to use `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` instead of legacy `pdfLaTeX`, and
2. You have a Chinese font in your operating system (e.g., MS-Windows, Mac OS X, Linux) and know the name of the font.

Then I suggest the following code (not using the `CJK` package because you want Chinese characters for a few parts).

*Note: In the following example, my operating system (MS-Windows 10) has the Chinese font `simsun.ttc`.*

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand{\mychinese}[1]{{\fontspec{SimSun}#1}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\mychinese{抽象}}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\mychinese{抽象}}

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\mychinese{你好}, blabla

\mychinese{关键词：} 

\mychinese{中图分类号：}F276.6
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Xiexie, I am not using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but I just posted the answer below which worked.

Comment: @Olivia Good news. I suggest XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (which is now pdfLaTeX) to typeset Chinese documents better.

Comment: Welcome @ChoF ChoF!